# How to Use Array.Exists with the Multi-dimensional string array

Tags: c#

I have a multi-dim string array something like this:-

```
string[,] names = new string[2, 2] { {"Rosy",""}, {"Peter","Albert"} };
```

Now i want to check the existence if the second index (Albert) holding the string is non-empty in the whole array. I just to check the existence of the non-empty string value in the second index.
I was thinking of using the Array.Exists. If there is any other better way, please share.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't really make sense of your question. Do you just want to know if there is a string "Albert" somewhere in the whole array?

Comment: "Albert" is an example. I just want to check if the second index contains  empty string value or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use `Array.Exists` here, because that only deals with the *values* - you're interested in the *position* too. I would just use a loop:

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < names.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(names[i, 1]))
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Rectangular arrays are basically a bit of a pain to work with in C#. If you had a *jagged array* - an array of arrays - it would be easy:

```
bool found = jagged.Select(x => x[1])
                   .Any(value => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value));
```

Comment: It is not a jagged array. Can you provide something else. I want to avoid the for iteration.

Comment: @Karan: I know it's not a jagged array, which is why I provided the first method. I'm saying it would be *easier* as a jagged array, and suggesting that you reconsider your design. *Something* is going to have to iterate over the data, after all... and in this case, doing it yourself is likely to be the simplest approach if you've got to work with a rectangular array. You could always put this into a utility method somewhere, of course.

Comment: @Karan: What's wrong with the for iteration? Not fashionable?